# Equivalence of categories between the loop algebra of $sl_{n+1}$ and the affine Weyl group of $GL_\ell(C)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, weyl-group, kac-moody-algebras

In this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9501003.pdf), Theorem 4.9 page 18, Charri and Pressley are claiming that there exists an equivalence of Categories between certain categories of the Lie algebra $\tilde{ \mathfrak g}=\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}\otimes \mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]$ and the affine Weyl group of $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb C)$.

There they say that the affine Weyl group of $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb C)$ is the semi-direct product $S_\ell \ltimes \mathbb Z_{\ell},$ where the action by automorphism is given by permuting coordinates. Why? How can I describe this affine Weyl group more intrinsically? Until now I've only heard about affine Weyl group of affine Lie algebras that are related to *semisimple* Lie algebras. And wouldn't it be more natural to consider the affine Weyl group of $\mathfrak sl_{n+1}$ instead of $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb C)$? Is there any relation between them?

Comment: Posted also on [math.se]: [Equivalence of categories between the loop algebra of $\mathfrak sl_{n+1}$ and the affine Weyl group of $GL_\ell(\mathbb C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418775). When [meta-tag:cross-posting], it is [recommended to link to other copies](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/2638#2638).

Comment: I'll delete the post at MSE then